# How SET IDENTITY_INSERT works?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How an I use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.TableName ON`?

Here's my error code:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'tbl_PurchaseRequest' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I run this query in SQL Server 2014 and it says `Command successful` but still in C# not worked.

My Code:

```
DBPurCon dbcon = new DBPurCon();

    public void Purchase1 (BELPurchase BELPur)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.tbl_PurchaseRequest ON";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_PurchaseRequest VALUES (@SID1,@Vendor,@Address,@Date,@Terms,@Qty1,@ITD1,@Unit,@UP1,@TP1,@ATT,@REQBY);";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID1", BELPur.SID1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor", BELPur.Vendor);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", BELPur.Address);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", BELPur.Date);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terms", BELPur.Terms);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty1", BELPur.Qty1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITD1", BELPur.ItD1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unit", BELPur.Unt1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UP1", BELPur.UP1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TP1", BELPur.TP1);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ATT", BELPur.AllTot);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REQBY", BELPur.ReqBy);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public void Request1 (BELPurchase BELPur)
    {  
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_RequestPreview VALUES (@ReqTit,@ReqBy,@Terms,@Unlock,@AllTot,'Request')";
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqTit", BELPur.ReqTit);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqBy", BELPur.ReqBy);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Terms", BELPur.Terms);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unlock", BELPur.Unlock);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AllTot", BELPur.AllTot);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

If I write this code in here, it always run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` query whenever I click `Purchase` button. Is it can only run once or multiple times?

Comment: Are you actually trying to insert into the `Identity` column? If so, why? If you're not - the problem is that you didn't specify a column list in the `insert` statement. It should be `INSERT INTO tbl_RequestPreview (ColumnName1, ColumnName2, etc) values (@Value1, @Value2, @etc)`.

Comment: Sir blorgbeard! I want to run the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` query in `tbl_PurchaseRequest`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Because the error said to do it? Do you understand what it does? Do you know what an `identity` column is?

Comment: Stop doing it. Or make that column not identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be executing the commands separately. You need to include the identity column name and its value.

We normally need to `IDENTITY_INSERT` on when we want to insert an Identity field to insert value from SQL Command instead of `Auto` so please include the `request_id` and its value.

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_PurchaseRequest] ON; 
        INSERT INTO tbl_PurchaseRequest VALUES (@ReqID,@SID1,@Vendor,@Address,@Date,@Terms,@Qty1,@ITD1,@Unit,@UP1,@TP1,@ATT,@REQBY); 
                    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tbl_PurchaseRequest] OFF;";

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqID", SomeNumber++);
```

> Is it can only run once or multiple times

Yes, you can run it multiple times as we set `OFF` after the Command

Comment: So Sir! @mohit-shrivastava you mean everytime I clicked the `Purchase` button, it always execute the query ON and OFF?

Comment: Hey @AnjelloJoshua what happened?? why u cry!! would it not solved your issue.

Comment: But Sir @mohit-shrivastava I got again the same error. Do I need to put `request_id` value like `1` to run the query? Is it the same in MySQL that even you're NOT put any `int` value in a column with `auto-increment` the MySQL consider is as `1` ?

Comment: Sir! @mohit-shrivastava I cried because I've been problem this for more than a week. I also recreate my database to work this :'(

Comment: is it mysql or sql server? it looks like Sql Server, not MySql (MySql has AUTO_GENERATED columns, Sql Server has Identity).

Comment: Sir! @mohit-shrivastava I'm just saying that I used MySQL before that the column has auto-increment that automatically increment by 1 even it has no value putted by user

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer. It might help you to understand what you have to do.

Comment: @mohit-shrivastavaHAHAHAHAHHA I KNEW IT! I have a gut feeling that I will put the value of `request_id` at first! But, it means SQL Server can't auto-generate value?

Comment: It could generate the values by itself but than u dont need `SET_IDENTITY` just the normal command would do.

Comment: What normal command Sir@mohit-shrivastava?. At first, I don't put `SET_IDENTITY` in my code, it just the error says that I need to put it? Should I create new question for this? In the beginning, I want to have `request_id` that is auto-increment that user will not put it's value.

Comment: You can post a new question with Screenshot of the table design and column properties. Which also shows Identity Specification.

Comment: Thank you Sir @mohit-shrivastava for always helping me in my difficult C# coding times. I really appreciate it ❤️